# Unable to select all contacts with phone numbers matching IN clause

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-contentprovider, android-sqlite

I'm trying to figure out how to query the Android Contact Content Provider with a list of phone numbers to retrieve contacts who have a phone number matching an item in that list. In straight SQL, I would use something like:

> `SELECT * FROM PHONES WHERE NUMBER IN ('1234','1235')`

I can't since I'm using the CP API and I seem to be missing something. This is a snippet of the `onCreateLoader()` query. There are no records that are returned in the result of this query, but I know those phone numbers exist for the contacts in the database. I think that no records are found because the phone number, as it is stored in the database, is formatted like so:

> `+1 425-555-1212`

I don't know if there is a way to query the CP and have it evaluate my `IN()` query list against unformatted data. Here is the `onCreateLoader()` query:

```
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    String[] projection = new String[] {    
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LABEL,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LOOKUP_KEY,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};
    return new CursorLoader(
            getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            projection,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER+" IN ('4255551212','4255551213')",
            null,
            null);
}
```

Using `PhoneLookup` (as shown below) with one of the phone numbers from the previous query actually yields a correct contact match so I assume there must be a way of doing this. Unfortunately, `PhoneLookup` does not appear to be able to handle a list of phone numbers, but only a single phone number:

```
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    String[] projection = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID,
            ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.LABEL,
            ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.LOOKUP_KEY,
            ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.NUMBER};
    return new CursorLoader(
            getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
            Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode("4255551212")),
            projection,
            null,
            null,
            null);
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this or is there an alternative way that would yield the same result? The result being:

- **Given a list of phone numbers, select all contacts that have a phone number in the list**

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Firstly I don't think there is a way to append multiple phone numbers in `ContactsContract.PhoneLookup`.

Secondly, as you said, the numbers stored in `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone` is usually formated. The way it determines whether two phone numbers are equal is based on [PhoneNumberUtils.compare(String num1, String num2)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html#compare%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).
By reading the source code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.java#PhoneNumberUtils.compareStrictly%28java.lang.String,java.lang.String,boolean%29) maybe you will come up with some idea how to generate a list of variations of a number and include them all in the `IN ('num1', 'num2', ...)`

If you have a lot of numbers to look for (i.e. almost same as whole contact size), I suggest query all NUMBER and the data you want from `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone` and store them in a `HashMap<NumberString, TheDataYouWant>`. (Before that you need to create a `NumberString` class which holds a string and override the `compareTo()` method to be return `PhoneNumberUtils.compare(this.string, anotherNumber.string);)`. Then you can search for the numbers you want in the `HashMap`.